# Implement jQuery library into vueJS project

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I will need to include a jquery library [jquery.ui.touch-punch.js](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch) in my project.

I had Implemented jQuery successfully but when I try to use jquery.ui.touch-punch.js it returns jQuery is not defined.

```
import $ from 'jquery/';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui'
import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.css'

//jquery.ui.touch-punch depnds on jquery
import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js'
```

The above is what I tried, but it seems it is not accessing the jQuery I implement before it.

Comment: A few question... where are these CSS and JS files located? Where are they located in respect of the location of the code? The reason I ask is that you need to provide a correct "relative" path. For example, if your file is in folder A and the library files in folder B, your relative path could be `../B/file.css`. If your code is in folder A and the library is in folder B, which is inside A, then your relative path would be either `./B/file.css` (the period means current folder) or `/A/B/file.css` (this one means from the root `/`, go into folder `A`, then folder `B`, then to the file.

Comment: In simple words, could you include the folder structure of your project, that shows where the your code is located and where these library files are located?

Comment: I would suggest using Sortable JS that has got a vuejs wrapper around it. But without the wrapper it works just as good as well. Sortable JS is still maintained, while this probably isn't. You will most likely also get into the problems when you start to tangle jquery and vue.

Comment: @Domatorov Because I am using .draggable(), but it's not working on mobile browser. Does Sortable JS does the same thing which makes the .draggable() works on mobile?